# Use a column in a SQL statement as a variable for subqueries populating subsequent columns

Tags: mysql, sql

Start with a simple query…

```
SELECT UserID AS ‘User ID’, UserName AS ‘User Name’ FROM tblUsers

OUTPUT:
User ID User Name
1   Joe
2   Bob
3   Larry
```

But then I need to run stored procedures that take the User ID as an Input:

```
GetUsersLastTransaction(pID_User)
```

who’s SQL could be anything  (`SELECT <whatever>  WHERE <whatever> = UserID`)

```
GetUsersAccountBalance(pID_User)
```

again, who’s SQL could be anything  (`SELECT <whatever>  WHERE <whatever> = UserID`)

So how can I make a query that would give me a single datatable like this

```
OUTPUT:
User ID User Name   Last Transaction    Account Balance
1   Joe     Transaction xyz     1000
2   Bob     Transaction pdq     1500
3   Larry       Transaction abc     1110
```

​

```
SELECT UserID AS ‘User ID’, UserName AS ‘User Name’, (
    SELECT <whatever>  
    WHERE <whatever> = ????
) AS ‘Last Transaction’, (
    SELECT <whatever>  
    WHERE <whatever> = ????
) AS ‘Account Balance’
```

So how do I use the value from the first column ('User ID') in the where clause (????) of my sub queries and have that work for each row?

Answer (score 0):

This is not going to work out well for you. What you are going to do is a Row By Row execution of your stored proc. Which means for N ROWS in your result set you will be executing your stored proc N times. As opposed to doing a set based approach(described below) which will only execute once.

What would be more efficient (but it wouldn't have much code re-use) is to put your select statement results into a temp table. Then copy the logic of your stored proc and do a join on your temp table.

Answer (score 0):

Just qualify the field name in the sub query. Consider this query:

```
SELECT UserID AS ‘User ID’, UserName AS ‘User Name’,
    (SELECT <whatever> FROM tbl2 WHERE tbl2.field = tblUsers.UserID)
FROM tblUsers
```

Now, if what you're trying to do is execute those stored procedures in a query - that's not going to happen. You'll need to convert those procedures to scalar valued user-defined functions. At that point you can actually call the function in place of the sub query. However, I **would not recommend that** unless it was absolutely necessary because of the complexity of the sub query.

Comment: This will do what he wants but it is a terrible way of doing it. This should be moved to a set based solution instead of an RBAR solution.

Comment: @gh9, though sub queries can have performance ramification, I don't think either of us know enough about the table being queried to understand what they may be. Consider the fact that a sub query written against a covered index has almost no performance ramifications. This is a **very** subjective conversation to start with almost no information.

Comment: you are correct in the fact that subquries are very subjective. But your example is a Correlated subquery. Which is terrible on performance. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery